# Terraform aws_instance specify login credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I am provisionng a Centos 7 instance in AWS with terraform with this code block

```
resource "aws_instance" "my_instance" {
   ami                    = "${var.image-aws-centos7}"
   monitoring             = "true"
   availability_zone      = "${var.aws-az1}"
   subnet_id              = "${var.my_subnet.id}"
   vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.my_sg.id}"]

   tags = {
     Name                  = "my_instance"
     os-type               = "linux"
     os-version            = "centos7"
     no_domainjoin         = "true"
     purpose               = "my test vm"
   }
```

The instance is created successfully but because i explicitly won't join it to my domain the autentication with my domain admin credentials fails which is understandable.

I login with ssh and the host is successfully added permenantly to known host.

I was searching in docs how to define local admin user name and password in terraform so that i can use those credentials to login to the instance.

I can't find an answer.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Adding new users on your instance should be performed from the inside of the instance. For this you could use [user_data](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/instance#user_data) attribute in your `aws_instance`.

[User data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) is a  script that will execute once your instance launches for the first time. Thus, instead of manually login into the instance through ssh, you would provide script in `user_data` that would reproduce the manual steps you take following instance launch.